# Finite dimensional Lie Group with a vector space structure (like diffeomorphisms)

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, lie-groups, diffeomorphism

Diffeomorphisms are a infinite dimensional Lie group, but you can also add and scalar multiply them like functions, so they act like a infinite dimensional vector space. Are there any non-trivial (not $\mathbb{R}^n$) finite dimensional Lie groups such that I can define $g_1 + \alpha g_2 \in G$ for $g_1, g_2 \in G, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$? If there isn't one is there a proof why this can't exist?

Comment: How does one add elements of a diffeomorphism group?

Comment: Or scalar multiply?

Comment: "such that I can define ..." -- you can define *some* real vector space structure on any Lie group of finite positive dimension, by just noting it is in bijection with $\mathbb R$ (cardinality!). In fact, this way you can turn it into a field. Alternatively you can make it isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. What I am getting at: Unless you refine this by including some compatibility constraints with the existing Lie group structure, this is a trivial question.

Comment: On the other hand, if the compatibility somehow preserves e.g. finite dimension, the question reads as: "Is there a (...) which I can give the structure of a finite dimensional real vector space, but not being isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$?" To which the answer is trivially no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the Heisenberg group $$H= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a &b\\
        0 & 1 &c\\
        0 & 0 &1 
        \end{pmatrix} :a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$
with the addition
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a &b\\
        0 & 1 &c\\
        0 & 0 &1 
        \end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & d &f\\
        0 & 1 &g\\
        0 & 0 &1 
        \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a+d &b+f\\
        0 & 1 &c+g\\
        0 & 0 &1 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and scalar multiple
$$\alpha \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a &b\\
        0 & 1 &c\\
        0 & 0 &1 
        \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & \alpha a &\alpha b\\
        0 & 1 &\alpha c\\
        0 & 0 &1 
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Perfect! I didn't expect it to be possible, but yes this works great.

Comment: As I say in comments to the question, this is a bit silly. You just write $\mathbb R^3$ in a way that identifies its elements with elements of a certain $3$-dimensional Lie group so that it looks appealing on first sight. But of course little here is compatible with the given Lie group structure.